# Recommendations for Papers on LLL Algorithm

Tags: reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra, cryptography

Asked a professor who does research in cryptography for a project opportunity, and he told me to go read about Lenstra-Lenstra-Lovasz or LLL algorithm. I read the following [paper](https://math.mit.edu/%7Eapost/courses/18.204-2016/18.204_Xinyue_Deng_final_paper.pdf) and found the topic to be very interesting and want to learn more about it.

Hence I want some recommendations for good papers on following topics (2 or 3 papers on each topic and up to advanced undergrad level proficient in basic abstract algebra and algorithms):

- Variations of LLL Algorithm
- Applications of LLL Algorithm
- Lattice-Based Cryptography (a general overview)

Comment: any reason why you don't ask your professor?